# Render a Partial View in _layout.cshtml using the partialview model instance with DBContext dependency injection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

At first I'd like to say I'm new to Asp.net Core and also with concepts of dependency injection (DI). I'm reading a lot trying understand it, so I ask for patience.

I'm trying Razor Pages (not MVC) and my goal is to render to "_layout.cshtml" a partial view, in which information obtained using the Entity Framework is available on all pages.

I added the DBContext in the Startup.cs file as follows:

```
  services.AddDbContext <AppDBContext> (options =>
  options.UseSqlServer (Configuration.GetConnectionString ("AppDBContext")
```

And in "PageModel" for MenuPartial.cshtml.cs

```
 public class MenuPartialModel: PageModel
    {
       
       private readonly AppDBContext _db;
      

        public MenuPartialModel (AppDBContext db)      
        {
            _db = db;
        }
                 
}
```

In the _layout.cshtm file I tried several ways to call PartialAsync with the instance of a new model:

If set new instance model like bellow I'll be using constructor without parameters, therefore the DbContext is not injected

```
@await Html.PartialAsync ("MenuPartial", new MenuPartialModel ())
```

And I also thought about using:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync ("MenuPartial", new MenuPartialModel (new AppDBContext ())
```

I believe that wouldn't be a correct approach. Because if the DbContext was injected automatically, why should I perform a new instance by passing connection parameters again?

What would be the best approach to achieve my goal? I thought about using ViewComponents, however, at first I would like to understand if there is any way to instantiate a model and use the constructor that injects the DBContext.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to understand if there is any way to instantiate a model and use the constructor that injects the DBContext.

In ASP.NET Core MVC, plain old CLR classes (POCOs) do not participate in ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection. The `MenuPartialModel` is a POCO (as are most MVC models). As a result, the framework will not automatically inject dependencies into it.

Some built-in ASP.NET Core MVC classes are wired into the dependency injection. These include (but are not limited to):

- Controllers,
- Tag Helpers,
- Razor Views,
- Razor Pages, and
- View Components.

The canonical approach in MVC is to inject dependencies (aka services) into one of those, and then to pass any data manually to the POCO model.

> What would be [a good] approach to achieve my goal?

Instead of Partial View, I would use a [View Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1). A view component is like a partial view that has a model, a view, and a controller.

The controller is `InvokeAsync`, which isn't exposed to HTTP, but it is still a controller [in the traditional sense](https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/), because it is responsible for binding the model to the view.

#### Basic View Component with Dependency Injection

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyApplication.Data;

public class MenuModel
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyOtherProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

    public MenuViewComponent(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var data = await dbContext...

        var model = new MenuModel 
        {
            MyProperty = data.FirstValue,
            MyOtherProperty = data.OtherValue,
        };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

You will also need a Razor file at one of these locations to act as the view.

```
/Pages/Shared/Components/Menu/Default.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Components/Menu/Default.cshtml
```

That `Default.cshtml` file will contain something like this:

```
@model MenuModel

<p>@Model.MyProperty</p>
<p>@Model.MyOtherProperty</p>
```

#### Using the View Component

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Menu")
```

#### Accessing the View Component with AJAX

Out of the box, View Components are not exposed to HTTP. To access them via AJAX, we need to [add an ASP.NET Core MVC Controller to reach them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1#invoking-a-view-component-directly-from-a-controller).

```
[Route("component/[action]")]
public class ViewComponentController : Controller 
{ 
    // ~/component/menu
    public IActionResult Menu() => ViewComponent("Menu");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shaun Luttin, you helped me understand a little bit dependency injection. Sorry if it's inconvenient, but in your opinion, what would be the most appropriate approach for displaying data (from a database) to be visible in the whole application?

Comment: Thank you very much, I had done something similar. However, I have a question about the ViewComponent. Is it possible to make an Ajax request for a ViewComponent that returns a view? I have seen something similar to this but with partial view.

Comment: Thank you very much again, now everything is getting clearer.