# Using a DI with partial views in asp.net core razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, razor-pages, partial-views

A partial view (working completely fine otherwise; when not using DI that is) is being consumed using the following line:

```cs
<partial
    name="Partials/SelectLoc"
    model="new Partials.SelectLocModel(new HttpClient(), (<this is the part with DI>))" />
```

The ctor for LocationList takes an object of `LocationDbContext` class which is basically a child of `DbContext`.
However, as it turns out, I am unable to instantiate the `LocationDbContext` in the call to the partial.

How do I correct this?

Comment: Also, is partial the same reason for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66007078/using-forms-in-partial-views-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages)?

Comment: Yes, I also mentioned this thread in my reply, but sorry, I cannot flag it.

Comment: Done, as in, marked as duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [`View components`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0) instead of partial view.A view component is like a partial view that has a model, a view, and a controller.You can directly inject Dbcontext into it.

```
public class YourViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
private readonly LocationDbContext dbContext;

public YourViewComponent (LocationDbContext dbContext)
{
    this.dbContext = dbContext;
}

public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
 //...
}
}
```

About the details you can see the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0#add-a-viewcomponent-class) or this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013825/render-a-partial-view-in-layout-cshtml-using-the-partialview-model-instance-wit).

**Edit:**

I think there also can Inject your services in your view like this(example).

```
@inject System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient
@inject WebApplication150.Data.WebApplication150Context context

<partial name="Partials/SelectLoc"
     model="new Pages.SelectLocModelModel(httpClient,context)"/>
```